# Don't keep history of resources

Tags: fhir-server-for-azure

I have an instance of Microsoft FHIR Server and I would like to disable the resource history. Is there a setting to enable/disable it, or do I need to change the "versioning, interaction, readHistory" properties on all resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The FHIR Server respects what is in the generated capability statement, however there is currently no way of doing this outside of editing the code. I'd recommend raising an issue to register interest in this feature (https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/issues)